ffmpeg filtergraph acrossfade non ordered
I have this filtergraph sequence:
[0:v]trim=start=10:duration=5,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,fps=30[v2];
[0:a]atrim=start=10:duration=5,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a2];

[0:v]trim=start=20:duration=5,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,fps=30[v3];
[0:a]atrim=start=20:duration=5,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a3];


[0:v]trim=start=30:duration=5,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,fps=30[v4];
[0:a]atrim=start=30:duration=5,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a4];

[0:v]trim=start=60:duration=5,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,fps=30[v1];
[0:a]atrim=start=60:duration=5,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a1];

[v12][v3]xfade=transition=radial:duration=1:offset=8[v23];
[a12][a3]acrossfade=d=1[a23];

[v23][v4]xfade=transition=fade:duration=1:offset=12[vo];
[a23][a4]acrossfade=d=1[ao];

[v1][v2]xfade=transition=wiperight:duration=1:offset=4[v12];
[a1][a2]acrossfade=d=1[a12];


The thing is that if I put the segments in chronological order, it works perfectly, but if I set it like this I got this error (I added some debug context):
...
[out_#0:0 @ 000002345029c280] EOF on sink link out_#0:0:default.
[fc#0 @ 000002344ddf3440] Filtergraph returned EOF, finishing
[fc#0 @ 000002344ddf3440] All consumers returned EOF
[out#0/mp4 @ 000002344e4307c0] sq: 0 EOF
[out#0/mp4 @ 000002344e4307c0] sq: finish 0; head ts 17
[out#0/mp4 @ 000002344e4307c0] sq: finish queue
[aost#0:1/aac @ 000002344ddfd480] Encoder thread received EOF
[aost#0:1/aac @ 000002344ddfd480] Could not open encoder before EOF
[aost#0:1/aac @ 000002344ddfd480] Task finished with error code: -22 (Invalid argument)
[aost#0:1/aac @ 000002344ddfd480] Terminating thread with return code -22 (Invalid argument)
[libx264 @ 000002344de00a80] frame= 446 QP=30.47 NAL=0 Slice:B Poc:120 I:80   P:601  SKIP:239  size=3870 bytes
...
[libx264 @ 000002344de00a80] frame= 508 QP=30.38 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:60  I:33   P:607  SKIP:280  size=3883 bytes
[libx264 @ 000002344de00a80] frame= 509 QP=31.81 NAL=0 Slice:B Poc:58  I:2    P:566  SKIP:352  size=2278 bytes
[vost#0:0/libx264 @ 000002344e42eac0] Terminating thread with return code 0 (success)
[out#0/mp4 @ 000002344e4307c0] Nothing was written into output file, because at least one of its streams received no packets.

Idk how to solve it, I tried using concat, and it works with it but I want the crossfade because concat have more duration whan the corssfade.
BTW the ffmpeg command is this
ffmpeg -y -loglevel debug -i input.mp4 -/filter_complex filters.script -map "[vo]" -map "[ao]"  out.mp4


try to add input twice → ffmpeg -i in -i in -/filter_complex ... and change disordered part to ... [1:v]trim=60:65,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,fps=30[v1];...

So I would have to put the same input for each segment if I want to guarantee a good output with disorder segments?

yes, in order not to get confused, it is better to make a separate source for each piece of video

So if I want to add for example 100 segments (for a recompilation video with fast changes)¡, 100 inputs, it doesnt sound very reliable.

Yes, there may not be enough RAM for 100 inputs. Split 100 inputs to 20 or less. And concat
